# How to get preview from «Drive Service» from «Class File»

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a public folder with a list of images and videos. The goal is to generate JSON with a list of images where each image will be an object and it contains a link to a preview image, a download image and meta data (latitudes, dimensions, etc.).

It is possible to get this info from «Class File»:

1. link to photo preview
2. link to video preview
3. metadata (latitudes, dimensions)

I have found one method from «Class File» .getBlob(). How do I parse this file?

Answer (score 0):

Its not getBlob.if you can't get to metadata and preview url from File, use instead the advanced drive services which is a wrapper for the full drive api.